# Create macvim in Applications folder

Tags: vim, homebrew, macvim

I ran `brew install macvim`, and I'm wondering if there's a way to access it outside of the terminal? I know I can create a link in my applications folder, but is there more native support for this? Or is my best bet just to download this guy https://code.google.com/p/macvim/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MacVim is actually a GUI application first, *that comes with a CLI executable that you can run in your shell.*

You can find the MacVim.app bundle in `/usr/local/Cellar/`, where Homebrew puts all the programs you install with it.

It is also possible to launch the MacVim GUI with:

```
$ mvim -g filename
```

Installing MacVim with Homebrew makes sense if you already use Homebrew to install the UNIX programs that you use regularly but installing Homebrew just to get MacVim is a pointless waste of time. Downloading MacVim [from the official source](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim/releases) is a much better idea IMO: simpler, quicker…

Comment: I actually do use Homebrew to install other things, but I'm not really that familiar with it; I just run the brew install when I run across something I need. It turns out what I was looking for was the `brew linkapps` command, but I didn't know that Homebrew installed the actual app bundle so that's helpful